# How add table rows dynamically and loading dynamic combobox with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm building a form where I need multiple entries with optional, for example Dynamic Combobox. What I have is basically this:

Image:
http://twitpic.com/a4ph8x

Every time a user presses the 'new row' button a new row of form inputs with dynamic combobox and other inputs should be added to the form, how can I do this in jQuery?

I'm sorry for asking maybe such a basic question but I'm still very green with jQuery, I could do this with PHP but I'm sure Javascript / jQuery plays a more appropriate role here.

Thanks!

Code:
http://www.4shared.com/file/BCaFsfC9/code.html

Comment: Please post relevant portions of your code directly for better assistance.

Comment: Please add code here using supplied formatting tags or someplace like pastie.org. Can't speak for everyone, but I won't download someone's code from an unknown source.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Jquery can do that very well.

Just pass a function on click say: addNewRow() on click of that button and append the new row in the html.

for example

```
function addNewRow()
{
$('.form').append('<input type="text" />');
}
```